# How to use javascript to get html special characters in text input

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

I want to sent some html special character to text field and then later use javascript to get it back in its original format: like if I sent "&pi", it will shows "π" on the text input, and when I use javascript to get it back, I should get "&pi", but I only can get "π", not "&pi". Please help, my code is like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function qpush(a) {
    document.getElementById('input').value += a;
}

function show(a) {
    alert(document.getElementById('input').value);
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="button" onclick="qpush('&pi;');" value="&pi;" />
<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="go" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you need the it for you could do one of 3 options:

1. use the javascript escape and unescape functions:

   var escaped = escape('π')   // escaped = "%u03C0" which unescape will turn back into π
2. If you have jQuery available it's html method might do the trick:

   $('input').val().html()
3. This is a hack but will work: Save a copy of the value the way you want it returned on a 'data-' attribute of the input element, this will validate in html5 and won't break in other doctypes.

   document.getElementById('input').setAttribute('data-originalValue', '&pi')

Comment: Thank you for the help, I use escaped form for data, and unescaped form for display, it works okay.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

The `value` property will give you text, not HTML.

<s>You could try `getAttribute('value')` but since `&pi;` and `π` are identically equivalent in HTML, a browser is entirely free to return `π` for that too.</s>

<s>Once the HTML has been converted into a DOM, there is no way to access the original HTML (short of downloading the HTML again with XHR and parsing the raw text of it yourself).</s>

If you want the data to be `"&pi;"` then the HTML for it needs to be `&amp;pi;`.

If you want that and the rendering on the button to be `π` then you need:

```
<button type="button" value="&amp;pi;">π</button>
```

(Keeping in mind the various bugs that old-IE has with the button element)

That will, of course, display `&pi;` when you copy the value to the text input.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but document.getElementById('input').getAttribute('value') return null.

Comment: Oh, missed that this was a different element you were getting the value from. `getAttribute` returns the attribute value (which is the default value of the input) not the current value.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to replace all occurrences of the character:

```
document.getElementById('input').value.replace(/π/g,"&pi;");
```

Comment: nice workaround, but I need to make it for all special chars, not just π.

Comment: @KelvinLi You could maintain an array of special entity mappings running the replace over.

Comment: I tried, but it looks like replace() cannot use for very special chars like π.